# Javascript example for task module?

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

After doing some research I came across this [example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-nodejs) about task module but it is in typescript. Where can I find pure javascript nodejs example for V3 SDK botbuilder ?

I would like to see how to integrate task module in my existing bot workflow.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was able to see js file. Thank you for your answer. I have one follow up question on task module but, it okay if you dont know the answer because its not related to this topic.

Do you know if task module works only on ms teams channel ? After reading I have started thinking its not going to work for local emulator.

Comment: Task Modules only work for ms teams channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is just TypeScript without the `typing`. It should be very easy to convert. In fact, there are even [online converters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) that are pretty simple to use.

You can also have the sample convert it for you by:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-nodejs
cd microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-nodejs
npm i
npm run build
```

Then look in the `/build/src` folder and you can see that sample compiled in JavaScript.

You can see it is written for V3 BotBuilder as well in [`package.json`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-nodejs/blob/master/package.json#L29): `"botbuilder": "^3.15.0",`

[image]